# Variable in Data flow task in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have developed SSIS package where in I have script component and Data flow task. Script component take 2 input variables namely Db2Con, SQLCon which are DB2 connection string and SQL Connection String. In this script component, I am dynamically generating Query and saving its value to the output variable namely DB2Qry. Now, In Data flow task, I am using this variable for source component.But it is not allowing me to do so with an Error "SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR". In script component, I have made this variable as 'ReadWrite Variable.' Please suggest if I am missing something.

Comment: can you let me know if the script task is failing ? or where actually it is throwing the error?

Answer (score 0):

SQL's EvaluateAsExpression should be set to FALSE.  You're not putting an expression into the variable, As you're  assigning a static value through your script.

and you need to manually set a "default" value for your SQL variable in the Variables pane, otherwise the OLE DB Source has nothing to use for the SQL statement at design time